# Is there any differences between python2 and python3 about adding menu bar to Frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to porting a project 2to3 on python, and stuck in tkinter.

In python2, there is no problem with adding menu bar to Frame in tkinter,

but python3 occured attribute error. (Frame object has no attribute 'tk_menuBar')

Is there any differences between python2 and python3 about adding menu bar to Frame in tkinter?

```
class TkMap(Map, tkinter.Tk):
""" Map with Tkinter GUI functions """
def __init__(self, cols, rows, value,
             width, height, widthMM, heightMM,
             title, menu = None, keybindings = []):
    """ TkMap extends Map and Tkinter """
    Map.__init__(self, cols, rows, widthMM, heightMM)
    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.title(title)
    if menu == None:
        menu = [('File',[['Exit',self.destroy]])]
    keybindings.append( ("<Configure>", self.changeSize))
    self.menuButtons = {}
    self.debug = 0
    self.application = 0
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.colScale = self.width / self.cols
    self.rowScale = self.height / self.rows
    self.addMenu(menu)

def addMenu(self, menu):
    """ Create a menu """
    self.mBar = tkinter.Frame(self,relief=tkinter.RAISED,borderwidth=2)
    self.mBar.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

    *for entry in menu:
        self.mBar.tk_menuBar(self.makeMenu(self.mBar, entry[0],entry[1]))*

    self.mBar.pack(side = "top")
```

PS. It's my first question, so i will be appreciated that if you point out my mistake about bad manners.

Comment: Running your code I get a syntax error. After fixing it I get another syntax error, then another one, then `NameError: name 'Map' is not defined`... Code that doesn't actually reproduce your problem is not helpful.

Comment: Your main mistake is posting non-working code. While it's possible in this specific case for us to see the problem, in general you need to supply code that we can copy and paste and then run. You have indentation errors, missing class definitions, missing imports, and several syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. In this case, i just want to know tk_menubar grammar between 2.x 3.x that can't find, so i didn't care code real worked. Next time in other question, i will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `tk_menuBar` in either python 2 or 3. The docstring for that function says this:

> """Do not use. Needed in Tk 3.6 and earlier."""

Note: tk 3.6 went obsolete back in the early 90's.

There is no way to attach a menu to a `Frame` widget. You can add instances of `Menubutton` to simulate a menubar, but you won't get a real menubar.

You can attach a `Menu` to the root window or to instances of `Toplevel` by configuring the `menu` attribute.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu()
fileMenu = tk.Menu()
editMenu = tk.Menu()
viewMenu = tk.Menu()

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)

root.configure(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ah... thank you for your answer. It is very tragic i can't use it anymore.

Comment: @agigom1993: you didn't lose any functionality. It was just a wrapper to make it a tiny bit easier to add menubuttons to a frame.